# Numerical differentiation using Stirling formula

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Is it correct to derivate Stirling formula with respect $x$ to obtain numericaly the value of the derivative of a function for a particular point?

Here is Stirling formula for the first five terms:

$P\left(x\right)=\:y_0+q\frac{\Delta y_{-1}+\Delta y_0}{2}+\frac{q^2}{2!}\Delta ^2y_{_{-1}}+\frac{q\left(q^2-1\right)}{3!}\frac{\Delta ^3y_{-2}+\Delta ^3y_{-1}}{2}+\frac{q^2\left(q^2-1\right)}{4!}\Delta ^4y_{-2}...$

with:

$q=\frac{x-x_0}{2}$

Comment: What is $y$, what is $Δy_{-k}$? At what points do you expect to obtain approximate values of the derivative?

Comment: In this video you can see how to do Stirling interpolation. But what I need is to obtain the derivate for a particular point.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCZIb9ue98Q

Comment: I want *you* to enhance *your question* with this information, it should be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: Ok. I wil do it in a while.